# OS X app NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need some help why is not setting text and image to NsTableview cell in OS X development.
Here is my demo code please help me out.

1. First this is my story board in that i have taken tablelist, and image& text Table cell view. Find the screen shot.
   [image: Storyboard Layout]
2. Now I am trying to setting the image and Textfield value of cell in NSTableview. And also my delegates are calling both here is my delegates code.

In NumberOfRowinTableView

```
{
    return [self.arrayData count];
}
```

In objectValueForTableColumn:(nullable NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row

```
{

NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

DataDoc *bugDoc = [self.arrayData objectAtIndex:row];
cellView.imageView.image = bugDoc.thumbImage;
cellView.textField.stringValue = bugDoc.data.title;
return cellView;

}
```

Also getting values from my array, here is my screenshot

[image]

And this values are not set in tableview cell and getting following output

[image]

I know it is very minor mistake, but not getting the where is the issue to set text and image to cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh god i found my mistake and got the solution.

1. I have to give a identifier of Table cell view in **Identity inspector**

[image]

2. Implement this method

   `-(nullable NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(nullable NSTableColumn *)tableColumn`row:(NSInteger)row

Instead of this for **View based** tableview content mode.

```
`-(nullable id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(nullable NSTableColumn *)tableColumn` row:(NSInteger)row
```